# Maven 3.0.5 + Windows 8 + jdk 7 issue

Tags: java, maven, windows-8, java-7

I trying to figure out what is happening with my maven. I have switch to windows 8 last days and found problem with building apps with maven (please see failure message at the bottom):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.400s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Apr 13 18:36:56 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Example: Could not resolve dep
endencies for project 
(Here are lots of libs)
Could not transfer artifact com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:pom:2.2.4-1 from/to central (
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org
 refused: connect: Address is invalid on local machine, or port is not valid on
remote machine -> [Help 1]
```

When switched to java 6, eveything is working fine. I have even disabled windows firewall, without any success though. Maybe someone has faced with that problem?

Here is my environment:

- Windows 8 x64
- JDK 7u17 (check on both, x86 and x64)
- Maven 3.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer look is so simple that I'm embarrassed to give but... . As I have written above I have disabled firewall / antyvirus but without any effect. However I don't add java as a exception to my antyvirus, which is as it turns out, scanning my apps and don't allow some to access event if it's disabled... . That's wierd but adding an exception in AV helped. Sorry for bother....